# nodemailer doesn't seem to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

Nodemailer sendMail function doesn't seem to do anything

I've tried debugging to see where it gets stuck

```
function sendEmail(){
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'email',
  to: 'different email',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
}
module.exports = {
sendEmail
};
```

I expect the email to be sent

Comment: What was the result of your debugging? Does ```sendMail``` callback get called?